# Algining the Author Name in the title page in the Book

Tags: titles, book-design

I am preparing report for my mini project. I have my name and register number and my supervisor. But These are not aligned. I mean, The supervisor name should appear in line with my author title. How do I  do that?

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,bindingoffset=0.2in,centering,headheight=0.3in,heightrounded]{geometry}  %% Can also use centering, or hcentering
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\newgeometry{margin=1in,bindingoffset=0in,centering,headheight=0.3in,heightrounded}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\centering
{\LARGE\scshape\textbf{DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING}\\[1cm]}
{\Large\scshape\textbf{PONDICHERRY ENGINEERING COLLEGE\\PUDUCHERRY$-$605 014}\\[1cm]}
{\Large\scshape\textbf{DATABASE MANAGEMENT SYSTEMS LABORATORY}\\[0.5cm]}
{\large\scshape\textbf{MINI PROJECT REPORT}\\[0.5cm]}

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
%{ \huge \bfseries WEB BLOG}\\[0.4cm]
{\huge\bfseries PROJECT - FACULTY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM\\[0.4cm]}
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
 \emph{Author:}\\
 \textsc{Subham Soni\\11TD0049}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:}\\
\textsc{Dr. L. Charuladha}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]
\includegraphics[scale=.50]{pecemblem}%\\[0.5cm]
\vfill
\Large \today
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two `minipage`s and those `flushleft` and `flushright`s. Just the following will do.

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \large
 \emph{Author:}       \hfill \emph{Supervisor:}\\
 \textsc{Subham Soni} \hfill \textsc{Dr. L. Charuladha}\\
 11TD0049
\end{minipage}
\vfill
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,bindingoffset=0.2in,centering,headheight=0.3in,heightrounded]{geometry}  %% Can also use centering, or hcentering
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\newgeometry{margin=1in,bindingoffset=0in,centering,headheight=0.3in,heightrounded}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\centering
{\LARGE\scshape\textbf{DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING}\\[1cm]}
{\Large\scshape\textbf{PONDICHERRY ENGINEERING COLLEGE\\PUDUCHERRY$-$605 014}\\[1cm]}
{\Large\scshape\textbf{DATABASE MANAGEMENT SYSTEMS LABORATORY}\\[0.5cm]}
{\large\scshape\textbf{MINI PROJECT REPORT}\\[0.5cm]}

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
%{ \huge \bfseries WEB BLOG}\\[0.4cm]
{\huge\bfseries PROJECT - FACULTY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM\\[0.4cm]}
\HRule \\[1.2cm]

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 \large
 \emph{Author:} \hfill \emph{Supervisor:}\\
 \textsc{Subham Soni} \hfill \textsc{Dr. L. Charuladha}\\
 11TD0049
\end{minipage}
\vfill
\includegraphics[scale=.50]{pecemblem}%\\[0.5cm]
\vfill
\Large \today
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `t` in the optional argument of the `minipage`s to have alignment at the top:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,bindingoffset=0.2in,centering,headheight=0.3in,heightrounded]{geometry}  %% Can also use centering, or hcentering
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\newgeometry{margin=1in,bindingoffset=0in,centering,headheight=0.3in,heightrounded}
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\centering
{\LARGE\scshape\textbf{DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING}\\[1cm]}
{\Large\scshape\textbf{PONDICHERRY ENGINEERING COLLEGE\\PUDUCHERRY$-$605 014}\\[1cm]}
{\Large\scshape\textbf{DATABASE MANAGEMENT SYSTEMS LABORATORY}\\[0.5cm]}
{\large\scshape\textbf{MINI PROJECT REPORT}\\[0.5cm]}

\HRule \\[0.4cm]
%{ \huge \bfseries WEB BLOG}\\[0.4cm]
{\huge\bfseries PROJECT - FACULTY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM\\[0.4cm]}
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
 \emph{Author:}\\
 \textsc{Subham Soni\\11TD0049}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:}\\
\textsc{Dr. L. Charuladha}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]
\includegraphics[scale=.50]{pecemblem}%\\[0.5cm]
\vfill
\Large \today
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.